# what is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/regexp/RESyntaxException in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I had installed STS sucessfully.But while running the project i am getting an eror like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/regexp/RESyntaxException.what is that??anyone can help me plz???

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing some depenedent library.

Try downloading regexp.jar or any similar jar containing the library, and add it your build path.

You can download jars from sites like [findjar.com](http://findjar.com)